# SFDX FieldService setting

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, work-order, fieldservice

I'm trying to work with WorkOrder object on my scratch org, but when I pull changes I'm getting error:

```
sfdx force:source:pull -f -u 13285 --loglevel debug
ERROR:  Settings type: 'FieldService' is unknown.
```